# subquery 2, subquery 3 not seeing main select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery

I have the following code which queries two databases (same schema, tied to the same application). One db holds service information, and the other transactions related to the service. The select is run in the transaction db. The output until "Volume of files/messages" is correct, but the select after that is returning a standalone value and not taking into consideration the main select. What is a workaround or the correct way to achieve the same for query 3 as it applies to the main select. I have included the output too. Thanks.

```
select distinct tctc_cntipcli as "Type of contract" ,tctc_cncclipu as "Contract number", tctc_cndocidc as "Client name", 
 tsrv_cndesser as "Service name", tsrv_cncveser as "Service number", tsrs_cnsubsdc as "Subservice name", tsrs_cnsubser as "Subservice name", tmap_cndesc as "Map" 
 , 
        (select count(tlof_cnlofrid)
        from service.kndtlof
        where tlof_cncclipu = tctc_cncclipu
        and tlof_cnservic = tsrv_cncveser
        and tlof_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
        and tlof_cnfhalta > trunc (sysdate, 'mm')
                            ) as "Volume of files/messages"
                            ,
                            (select count(app_data_id)
                            from app_data ad, status ss, internal_transactions it, service.kndtexe ke, service.kndtctc kc, service.kndtsrv kv, service.kndtsrs ks
                            where ad.int_tran_id = ss.int_tran_id
                            and ss.int_tran_id = it.int_tran_id
                            and
                            (
                              (it.credit_acct = ke.texe_cnasupro)
                            or
                              (it.debit_acct = ke.texe_cnasupro)
                            )
                            and ke.texe_cncclipu = kc.tctc_cncclipu
                            and ke.texe_cnfuncid = kv.tsrv_cncveser
                            and ke.texe_cnsubser = ks.tsrs_cnsubser
                            and ad.entry_timestamp > trunc (sysdate, 'mm')

                            ) as "Volume of Payments"

                          from service.kndtctc, service.kndtexe, service.kndtscm, service.kndtsrv, service.kndtsrs, service.kndtmap
                          where tctc_cncclipu = texe_cncclipu
                          and texe_cnfuncid = tsrv_cncveser
                          and texe_cnfuncid = tsrs_cncveser
                          and texe_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
                          and texe_cncclipu = tscm_cncontra
                          and tscm_cnmapco = tmap_cnmapco
                          and tscm_cnservic = tsrv_cncveser
                          and tscm_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
                          and tctc_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and texe_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tscm_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tsrv_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tsrs_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tmap_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          order by tctc_cncclipu
                          ;
```

And the output:

```
Type of contract||Contract number||Client name||Service name||Service number||Subservice name||Subservice number||Map||Volume of files/messages||Volume of Payments
C  50008753 Change Name  ACH  3085  ACH_IN1  I1  Sungard 820 ACH  31  16884 
C  50008753 Change Name  ACH  3085  ACH_IN4  I4  Sungard 820 ACH  0   16884 
C  50008753 Change Name  ACH  3085  ACH_OUT1 O1  827 NOC and Ret  1   16884 
C  50008753 Change Name  ACH  3085  ACH_OUT4 O4  827 NOC and Ret  0   16884
```

Also, can i use the max function to only make the repeating fields appear once in the output. Those could be up to the first 5 elements in the main select based on ordering.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your second question isn't clear enough for me to provide any suggestions.  What would the expected output be relative to the current output shown?

Answer (score 0):

Your second scalar sub query identified as "`Volume of Payments"` is uncorrelated to the outer query unlike your first scalar sub query identified as `"Volume of files/messages"` which is correlated to the outer query.

You can correlate your second scalar sub query by removing the extra `service.*` table references and instead use correlated values.

In doing this your subquery:

```
,(SELECT COUNT( app_data_id )
     FROM app_data ad
        , status ss
        , internal_transactions it
        , service.kndtexe ke
        , service.kndtctc kc
        , service.kndtsrv kv
        , service.kndtsrs ks
    WHERE ad.int_tran_id   = ss.int_tran_id
    AND ss.int_tran_id     = it.int_tran_id
    AND(( it.credit_acct   = ke.texe_cnasupro )
    OR( it.debit_acct      = ke.texe_cnasupro ) )
    AND ke.texe_cncclipu   = kc.tctc_cncclipu
    AND ke.texe_cnfuncid   = kv.tsrv_cncveser
    AND ke.texe_cnsubser   = ks.tsrs_cnsubser
    AND ad.entry_timestamp > TRUNC( sysdate, 'mm' )
  ) AS "Volume of Payments"
```

Would be transformed into this subquery:

```
,(SELECT COUNT( app_data_id )
     FROM app_data ad
        , status ss
        , internal_transactions it
    WHERE ad.int_tran_id   = ss.int_tran_id
    AND ss.int_tran_id     = it.int_tran_id
    AND(( it.credit_acct   = texe_cnasupro )  -- <= These two predicates correlate 
    OR( it.debit_acct      = texe_cnasupro ) )-- <= your subquery to the outer query
    AND ad.entry_timestamp > TRUNC( sysdate, 'mm' )
  ) AS "Volume of Payments"
```

If the above query has the wrong granularity, you can adjust it by adjusting which columns from the outer query you use to correlate the scalar sub query.

Further review of your original query shows that the `service.kndtexe.texe_cnasupro` column I chose to correlate the scalar sub query isn't used in your outer query, but the these three columns:

- `service.kndtctc.tctc_cncclipu`
- `service.kndtsrv.tsrv_cncveser`
- `service.kndtsrs.tsrs_cnsubser`

are.  Therefore try this instead:

```
(SELECT COUNT( app_data_id )
   FROM app_data ad
      , status ss
      , internal_transactions it
      , service.kndtexe ke
  WHERE ad.int_tran_id   = ss.int_tran_id
  AND ss.int_tran_id     = it.int_tran_id
  AND(( it.credit_acct   = ke.texe_cnasupro )
  OR( it.debit_acct      = ke.texe_cnasupro ) )
  AND ke.texe_cncclipu   = tctc_cncclipu -- <= Correlate with these three values
  AND ke.texe_cnfuncid   = tsrv_cncveser -- <= similarly to the other sub query
  AND ke.texe_cnsubser   = tsrs_cnsubser -- <= "Volume of files/messages"
  AND ke.texe_cnestado IN( '01', '03' )  -- Plus this filter?
  AND ad.entry_timestamp > TRUNC( sysdate, 'mm' )
) AS "Volume of Payments"
```

Comment: Thank you Sentinel. I don't think its correlated perfectly yet because now im getting multiples on the "volume of payments" query which is making the distinct on the outer query non-working.

Comment: Thank you again Sentinel. Unfortunately the output still is inconsistent with what i was expecting. I added your edit but I think i need to "filter" the "volume of payments" down to the map level so i connected another table that ties back to the map table, and the results are still skewed.  See below please...

Comment: AND ke.texe_cncclipu   = tctc_cncclipu 
AND ke.texe_cnfuncid   = tsrv_cncveser 
AND ke.texe_cnsubser   = tsrs_cnsubser 
AND ke.texe_cncclipu = tscm_cncontra   
AND km.tscm_cnmapco = tmap_cnmapco

Comment: Perhaps you just need to add the following predicate into the sub query `AND ke.texe_cnestado  IN( '01', '03' )` so that you only count the records matching this requirement.